# How can I fix rules for eslint mustache in Vue

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I need to change the rules for showing HTML code from this

```html
<v-btn to="/stores" class="grey--text px-10" outlined color="white">{{
$t("common.back")
}}</v-btn>
```

to this:

```html
<v-btn to="/stores" class="grey--text px-10" outlined color="white">
        {{$t("common.back")}}
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Not sure that you can enforce this with Prettier. Add a new line before `{{` and after `}}` and then let it format it.

Comment: They aren't equivalent, whitespaces may impact the way html is rendered, this is the reason the former is enforced. If you're sure it's ok, you can add multiple lines yourself and it will be formatted correctly

Comment: @EstusFlask oh right, that's why! Most of the time it doesn't matter but there are some cases when it can be quite important indeed.